# How to call the custom component from angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I am trying to build an Angular 9 project and I am a beginner, I am trying a very simple example by creating a custom component which includes a .ts,.html file and I am trying to bind those files while running. I have created

```
test.component.ts
test.component.html
```

I have included the component in the NgModule

Below is the link where I have hosted the project. Please help, I am new to this technology.

[Project link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q3jnau?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.html)

Comment: @MaihanNijat i have included  a file test.component.html & want that to show in the output

Comment: It depends on how you want to use it. if your created unrelated component You need to use it with routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your relation between components.

If they are unrelated components you can use [routing](https://angular.io/guide/router) [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oaxxvx)

You need to import routing module to app module

```
imports:[ BrowserModule, FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'test', component: testComponent }
          ]) 
  ]
```

then put  `<router-outlet ></router-outlet>` to app.component.html this will routing tag to use it.

and u can route like 
`<a routerLink="/test">Test</a>`

if you want to make it as default page then put this inside routing in app.module

```
 {path:"",redirectTo:"test",pathMatch:"full"},
```

if they are parent/child then you can use

```
<test></test>
```

in your demo hello component is a kind of example for this.